# Electron distribution in Low Earth Orbit

Tags: electrons, atmospheric-science, plasma-physics, satellites

I have been searching online for some kind of pdf function that describes the charged electron distribution in Low Earth Orbit in regards to their energies. Any ideas on whether something like that exists? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would recommend looking up papers using data from the FAST satellite and sounding rockets.  The former had really good electron velocity distribution measurements at a high cadence.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. The closest I've been able to find is a Monte Carlo calculation of the altitude profile of energy deposition by electrons in the mean atmosphere. From their model, you may somehow be able to extract a function to describe electron distributions.

The report is called "Energy deposition by auroral electrons in the atmosphere" published in the Journal of Atmospheric and Terrestrial Physics in 1970 by Berger et al.